# Can't sign in to Gitlab from Firefox

Tags: firefox, gitlab

Firefox 68.0.1. I can't sign in to Gitlab. I get an HTTP 422 error with the following message:

```
The change you requested was rejected.
Make sure you have access to the thing you tried to change.
Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a mistake.
```

Cleaning all data in browser doesn't help.

With Chromium I don't have any problems and I can sign in as expected.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because closing and reopening the browser resolved whatever the issues were. As such, this question is of little benefit to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed. Firefox fixed it self.

Comment: Is this perhaps a recurring problem in newer versions of Firefox? I have this issue with version 75.0 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

There 2 choice:

1. Allowe cookies (without 3rd party cookies) on Firefox
2. Set or resetting system clock

These Work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem (Firefox 122). I opened dev tools and cleared all the data for the site, and then I was able to login normally.